# How to handle missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Can't get a result from this function. Every time get the error: missing ) after argument list.

```
    function highAndLow(numbers) {
     var Strings = numbers;
     var newArr = Strings.split(' ');
     var maxNum = Math.max.apply(null, newArr);
     var minNum = Math.min.apply(null, newArr);
     return maxNum + " " + minNum;
   };

var top5 = highAndLow(4 3 1);
console.log(top5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass them as as string! Seeing as you are using `Strings.split()`!

```
highAndLow("42 17 3");
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are splitting the passed values inside your `highAndLow` function, I would suggest to pass them as a `String`

Like this
`var top5 = highAndLow('4 3 1');`

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
var top5 = highAndLow(4 3 1);
```

is invalid JavaScript. It looks like you want the argument to the function to be a string, so you need quotes:

```
var top5 = highAndLow("4 3 1");
```

---

Separately: Within the function, this line:

```
var Strings = numbers;
```

serves no purpose. Just use `numbers` directly.

Answer (score 0):

without quote this parameter behave as a JS variable, but this parameter should be a valid string thats why quote the value

```
var top5 = highAndLow('4 3 1');
    console.log(top5);
```

Comment: wirthout quote this parameter behave as a JS variable, but this parameter should be a valid string thats why quote the value.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will works for you,we have to pass string to this function
 either you can call like this

```
var top5 = highAndLow('4 3 1');
```

or define a string and pass that variable

```
var num = '4 3 1';
var top5 = highAndLow(num);
```